# Xamarin Line Breaking does not seem to honor Horizontal Options or Row Height AUTO

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have the following Xaml inside a Grid:

```
<Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Special characters" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
```

The Row Height is AUTO. When the column is wide enough for the text all works as expected. But if the column becomes so narrow that the text does not fit on one line, Xamarin seems to honor neither the HorizontalOptions="End" nor the Row Height of AUTO. I get something like the following (I am using | to represent the width of the column) but with the bottom half of the word "characters" cut off.

```
|Special        |
|Characters     |
```

If I force the break with a hard line break ( & # 10 ;) then it solves the row height issue -- all of the word "characters" appears -- but the justification is better but still wrong:

```
|     Special   |
|     Characters|
```

I have tried various combinations of End and EndAndExpand and Center and CenterAndExpand.

Anyone have a solution or a clue?

Thanks,

Comment: `HorizontalTextAlignment="End"`

Comment: Yes! Thanks. This is my first Xamarin project and the difference between HorizontalTextAlignment and HorizontalOptions escaped me. @Jason, you wrote this as a comment so I can't mark it as an answer (I think).

Comment: Interesting. It solves the right justification but not the Row Height Auto issue. If I take out the hard line break and just let it break on its own at the blank then the text right-justifies but the bottom half of "characters" disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HorizontalTextAlignment=“End”`